# Combining 3 Lists into a lists of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I just started to learn Python, and a completely a noob at it. So what I want to do is merge 3 lists into a lists of dictionary

```
country= ["Japan", "Malaysia", "Philippine", "Thailand"]
capital = ["Tokyo", "Kuala Lumpur", "Manila", "Bangkok"]
currency = ["Yen", "Ringgit", "Peso", "Bath"]
```

into a list in this format:

```
data = [{"country":"Japan", "capital":"Tokyo", "currency":"Yen"}, {"country":"Malaysia", "capital":"Kuala Lumpur", "currency":"Ringgit"}, {"country":"Philippine", "capital":"Manila", "currency":"Peso"},{"country":"Thailand", "capital":"Bangkok", "currency":"Bath"}]
```

And then print the new list in this format:

```
Capital of Japan is Tokyo, and the currency is Yen.
Capital of Malaysia is Kuala Lumpur, and the currency is Ringgit.
Capital of Philippine is Manila, and the currency is Peso.
Capital of Thailand is Bangkok, and the currency is Bath.
```

Comment: BTW, the Thai currency is the baht, not the bath :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple list comprehension with `zip` is all you need:

```
data = [{'country':coun, 'capital': cap, 'currency': curr} for coun, cap, curr in zip(country, capital, currency)]
```

You can then iterate through `data` and print as so:

```
for dictionary in data:
    print("Capital of {0} is {1} and currency is {2}".format(dictionary['country'],dictionary['capital'], dictionary['currency']))
```

---

### Readability Tips

Note that, like all structures within brackets, you can split a list comprehension into multiple lines:

```
data = [{'country':coun, 'capital': cap, 'currency': curr}
        for coun, cap, curr in zip(country, capital, currency)
       ]
```

You may also want to save the string to format in a variable (possibly with other constants) as well so that it does not end up buried inside other statements:

```
message = "Capital of {0} is {1} and currency is {2}"
for dictionary in data:
    print(message.format(dictionary['country'],dictionary['capital'], dictionary['currency']))
```

You can also specify the keys in the format space instead of `{0} {1}` then use `.format_map` to map the keys from the dictionary to the string:

```
message = "Capital of {country} is {capital} and currency is {currency}"
for dictionary in data:
    print(message.format_map(dictionary))
```

Comment: You are missing the ending square bracket!

Comment: would you humour me and offer an alternate version that is split onto two lines? [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) suggests a maximum of 79 characters per line and you are quite a bit over that.

Comment: So basically i just need to do a list comprehension with zip, if i want to combine multiple lists?
@Akhsat Mahajan thank you so much for the provided solution.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I'm actually not sure if doing `/` in the middle of a list comprehension is the right thing to do. If you have the time, I'd appreciate your edits.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Thanks!